# Why are interrupts not triggered during an infinite printing loop task

Tags: timer, x86, scheduler, osdev, multitasking

Specifically, I have two tasks `fn` and `fn1` that are being run by a scheduler. The code for each is below:

```
int fn(void *arg)
{
  for(;;) {
    printf("a");
  }
  return 6;
}

int fn2(void *arg)
{
  for(;;) {
    printf("b");
  }
  return 6;
}
```

Each of these functions are scheduled by a `schedule` function, which is called on each PIT interrupt:

```
// See https://wiki.osdev.org/Programmable_Interval_Timer
// The oscillator used by the PIT chip runs at (roughly) 1.193182 MHz.
#define TIMER_INPUT_CLOCK_FREQUENCY    1193180
#define TIMER_CHANNEL_0_DATA_PORT    0x40
#define TIMER_CHANNEL_1_DATA_PORT    0x41
#define TIMER_CHANNEL_2_DATA_PORT    0x42
#define TIMER_COMMAND_PORT    0x43

// number of ticks since system booted
uint32 g_ticks = 0;
// frequency in hertz
uint16 g_freq_hz = 0;

int task_switch_needed = 0;

// See https://wiki.osdev.org/Programmable_Interval_Timer
void timer_set_frequency(uint16 f) {
    g_freq_hz = f;
    uint16 divisor = TIMER_INPUT_CLOCK_FREQUENCY / f;
    // set Mode 3 - Square Wave Mode
    outportb(TIMER_COMMAND_PORT, 0b00110110);
    // set low byte
    outportb(TIMER_CHANNEL_0_DATA_PORT, divisor & 0xFF);
    // set high byte
    outportb(TIMER_CHANNEL_0_DATA_PORT, (divisor >> 8) & 0xFF);
}


void timer_handler(REGISTERS* r) {
    g_ticks++;
    printf("timer triggered at frequency %d\n", g_ticks);
    schedule();
}

void timer_init() {
    timer_set_frequency(20);
    isr_register_interrupt_handler(IRQ_BASE, timer_handler);
}

void sleep(int sec) {
    uint32 end = g_ticks + sec * g_freq_hz;
    while (g_ticks < end);
}
```

The functions are made tasks here:

```
uint32 *stack = kmalloc (0x400) + 0x3F0;

    task_t *t = create_task(&fn, (void*)0x567, stack);
    
    uint32 *stack2 = kmalloc (0x400) + 0x3F0;
    
    task_t *t2 = create_task(&fn2, (void*)0x567, stack2);
```

However, the timer is only invoked once, and the first function, namely `fn` just keeps executing.

OS Source: https://filebin.net/by6ix0jhs1ibcg0i

Comment: Do you send an EOI to acknowledge to the PIC that you've processed the interrupt? An EOI for IRQ0 through IRQ 0x07 (inclusive) which includes IRQ0 - is done by sending a 0x20 to the Master PIC at port 0x20. Do that before you IRET. We don't know what your schedule function looks like and how it all fits together. A [mcve] would be useful.

Comment: I have uploaded the full kernel code, it isn't really a minimal reproducible example, but the other components of the kernel can be ignored if they aren't relevant.

Comment: Also, without the schedule function calling these two tasks in the timer interrupt routine, the timer works fine.

Comment: I attempted to send the EOI, but nothing changed

Comment: Your code (in the zip file) does send EOIs but the problem is more fundamental. You receive a timer interrupt, `timer_handler` gets called in interrupt context and the scheduler ends up starting `fn` which prints `a` in an infinite loop. While `fn` will have interrupts enabled because you set eflags with IF=1 when the task starts, you won't get another timer interrupt (or any interrupt for that matter) until an EOI is sent to the PICs. Because of this once `fn` goes into the infinite loop no fiuther timer interrupts will occur and thus the scheduler will never have a chance to switch tasks.

Comment: What I have attempted to do is set a variable, `do_task_switch` as a flag, either 0 or 1 that is set to 1 during `timer_handler`. In my main function, I have an infinite while loop that detects if `do_task_switch == 1`, than it will set it to 0, and run the `schedule` function. What happens however, is the schedule function is only called once, on the first timer interrupt, and fails to do so in any subsequent ones.

Comment: It's only called once for the reason given earlier. Once your code schedules and switches to the first task it sits in an infinite loop printing `a` and it never reaches the EOI code that acknowledges you processed IRQ0 (timer). Without acknowledging with an EOI you will not get another timer interrupt (or any external interrupt in the case of IRQ0 not being acknowledged). This is the case even if you have interrupts enabled (IF=1)

Comment: Should I call the EOI at the end of switch_task, or before the task

Comment: You can call it before `switch_task` but I haven't investigated fully whether your code as written has potential other issues.

Comment: I call the EOI before switch task, and a GPF appears to happen, causing qemu to reboot.

Comment: That would be a different problem of course. As I said I haven't actually looked at all how your code interacts. An observation though is that your `switch_task` seems to be based on something that was part of some co-operative multitasking code. I'd actually recommend compiling with debug output (gcc's `-g` option and nasm's `-g` option) and use QEMU and GDB remote debugging facility to debug. A script that launches QEMU and GDB can be found here: https://pastebin.com/TYtXGHgC .

Comment: If you don't have at least NASM 2.16.01 I highly recommend downloading the latest stable source and building it as it has a problem with debug output that was recently fixed. I suspect though that you received a second timer interrupt and the `switch_task` failed trying to switch the second time. THe script in the last comment also runs QEMU with the `-d int` option and redirects output to `dbg.log` . That log can help as it will tell you what exceptions and interrupts occurred before failure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255003/discussion-between-xingharvey-and-michael-petch).

Comment: Its been a while, but I have decided to return to the project, when you note that switch_task() jumps to the wrong memory address, could this have anything to do with the memory management code, or perhaps compiler optimizations?